# AFNetworking POST Never Succeeding - Unexpected Behavior Occurring on Different Devices

Tags: ios, post, afnetworking, freeze

I am currently developing an iOS app that allows a user to post a classified listing for other users to see. On all devices, that app hangs in a "O% Uploaded" `SVProgressHUD` for a while before displaying "Our server is temporarily unavailable. Please try again later.", which is what I have coded in the case of a Status Code 500 error from the server side. However, on the iOS simulator, everything works smoothly.

All other functionality involving network requests is working perfectly except for this, so it must have something to do with the actual upload process. I've posted the corresponding code below; if you require anything additional to help figure this out, please let me know.

**Networking Code**

```
- (IBAction)publishPressed:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
    [SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Loading..." maskType:SVProgressHUDMaskTypeBlack];

    // Set the params for the API call in an NSMutableDictionary called mutableParams.

    // Create the form request with the post parameters and image data to pass to the API.
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[UAPIClient sharedClient] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" 
                                                              path:@"mobPost.php" 
                                                              parameters:mutableParams 
                                                              constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        if (self.imageHasBeenSet) {
            [self.listingImageView.image fixOrientation];
            NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.listingImageView.image);
            [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"userfile" 
                      fileName:@"postImage.png" mimeType:@"image/png"]; 
        }
    }];

    // Create the `AFJSONRequestOperation` from the form request, with appropriate success and failure blocks.
    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [[AFJSONRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseJSON) {
        if ([[responseJSON objectForKey:@"status"] intValue] == 1) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [SVProgressHUD showSuccessWithStatus:@"Success!"];
            });
            // Pass a message back to the delegate so that the modal view controller
            // can be dismissed successfully.
            [self.delegate uCreateListingTableViewController:self didCreateListing:YES];
        } else {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [SVProgressHUD showErrorWithStatus:@"Post failed. Please try again."];
            });
            NSLog(@"Status %@", [responseJSON objectForKey:@"status"]);
        }
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [SVProgressHUD showErrorWithStatus:@"Our server is temporarily unavailable. Please try again later."];
        });
    }];

    [operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [SVProgressHUD showSuccessWithStatus:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lli", (totalBytesWritten / totalBytesExpectedToWrite)] stringByAppendingString:@"% Uploaded"]];
        });
    }];

    [[UAPIClient sharedClient] enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];
}
```

**UAPIClient.m**

```
#import "UAPIClient.h"
#import "AFJSONRequestOperation.h"

static NSString * const kUAPIBaseURLString = @"hiding string for privacy";

@implementation UAPIClient

+ (UAPIClient *)sharedClient {
    static UAPIClient *_sharedClient;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        _sharedClient = [[UAPIClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kUAPIBaseURLString]];
    });

    return _sharedClient;
}

- (id)initWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)url {
    self = [super initWithBaseURL:url];
    if (self) {
        [self registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];

        // Accept HTTP Header; see http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.1
        [self setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: Well if your request is failing you are never dismissing the SVProgressHUD. Try adding `[SVProgressHUD showErrorWithStatus:@"Post failed. Please try again."];` to the failure block. This isn't an answer to fix your problem, but that could be why you think it's "freezing"

Comment: @mkral I actually did include this in a previous build of the app, and it apparently was never reaching the failure block, because the app still got stuck with the "Loading..." `SVProgressHUD`.

Comment: Do you know if the operation is actually completing? Maybe you should add a progress block to check that everything is being downloaded.

Comment: @mkral I added the code for a progress block to the question, but I don't know if the code is correct because even when the app is successful on my device, it only displays "1% Uploaded" before successfully completing.

Comment: Your progress block is writing `(totalBytesWritten / totalBytesExpectedToWrite)` so `1 is 100%` in this case. You can do `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", floorf((float)(totalBytesWritten / totalBytesExpectedToWrite))*100] stringByAppendingString:@"% Uploaded"]`

Comment: @mkral Ah, of course, my mistake. Ok, I've added this code, and the tester is just getting an `SVProgressHUD` repeatedly saying "0% Uploaded", which means the process is never completing. Any ideas?

Comment: @mkral It turns out it was a threading issue with `SVProgressHUD`, but now that I've fixed it, the networking code is working only on the iOS simulator and none of the devices. I've updated the question to reflect this. Any ideas?

Comment: I'll have to look at it more later but are you sure `postImage.png` is on the device? It could be that you only have a reference to it on your mac.

Comment: @mkral From my understanding, this method gives the image file the name `postImage.png` when it uploads it to the server; it's not any file that's stored locally on my Mac.

Comment: What I meant is, when you added the `postImage.png` to the project did you check the `Copy if needed...` box? If the image is outside the project scope it can still have a reference to that image and work on the simulator.

Comment: Wait, did I misunderstand completely? Are you saving that image with the name `postImage`?

Comment: The picture that is taken on the app is uploaded with the name `postImage.png`.

Comment: Wow, I feel dumb now. I guess I didn't read it closely. I thought you were uploading `[UIImage imageNamed:@"postImage.png"]`